# Responsive photo gallery with upload, admin, albums and pagination?

Tags: javascript, images, php, gallery, uploader

Is there any free library or script/code or tutorial (in php, ajax, javascript) for a photo gallery that can be integrated in website and with features mentioned below?

I did a lot of Google but not a single result came up which matched the requirement. In fact most of the results were related to Bootstrap or Wordpress plugins.

The features/functionality I am looking for:
Is there any free library or script/code or tutorial (in php, ajax, javascript) for a photo gallery that can be integrated in website and with features mentioned below?

The features/functionality I am looking for:

- Display of albums
- Admin section to manage (add, edit, delete) photos    and albums
- Responsive layout for zoomed image and thumbnails
- Pagination for photo thumbnails

Comment: Can you integrate [mediagoblin](https://mediagoblin.org/pages/tour.html) into your website? It would be great to know your 'integration' requirements for this question.

Comment: Thank you @SvetlanaT. for suggesting mediagoblin. From what I see, it does most of what DesV wants, but not what I would expect of a responsive layout.